# Heroku.yml file. How to pass environment variables from .env file?

Tags: heroku, environment-variables

I have been looking for this solution for a while but the documentation about the `heroku.yml` file is quite limited at the moment.

I have this **heroku.yml** file:

```
build:
  docker:
    web: Dockerfile
  config:
    SECRET_KEY: django-secret-key

setup:

  addons:
  - plan: heroku-postgresql
    as: DATABASE
  config:
    DB_NAME: database-name
```

I have my environment variables in an `.env` file. I don't want anybody to have access to them. This `.env` file is added to `.gitignore` and `.dockerignore` files. The thing is, if I harcode them to the `heroku.yml` file they'll be accessible both from *git* and from the *docker container*

My question is the next, is there a way to pass these environment variables from the `.env` file to the `heroku.yml` file withouth hardcoding them?

Answer (score 2):

You need to add an `env_file: .env` to `setup.config` in `heroku.yml` and then add your config vars to heroku in the settings

[image: config-vars]

Example of my `heroku.yml`

```yaml
setup:
  config:
    env_file: .env # <-- important line
build:
  docker:
    web: Dockerfile
run:
  web: npm run start
```

This `heroku.yml` should work for you:

```yaml
setup:
  addons:
  - plan: heroku-postgresql
    as: DATABASE
  config:
    env_file: .env
build:
  docker:
    web: Dockerfile
```

Comment: What does `env_file: .env` do? If the config vars don't show up on Heroku I don't think it does anything.

Comment: This actually doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

Your `.env` shouldn't be committed so Heroku won't have access to it. You'd usually set the env vars one-by-one either by hand or via the CLI. You can automate setting them from the .env file:

```
xargs -a .env -I {} heroku config:set {}
```